# Cannot create or delete PayPal sandbox account in Developer account

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have an account on developer.paypal.com and several months ago I created 8 sandbox test accounts, both business and personal.  Now, when I go back to my account Dashboard > Accounts and I try to either create a new account or I check to delete one, it returns a generic error message like this:
"We're sorry, something went wrong during account deletion. Some of the test accounts you had selected may not have been deleted. Please try again."

It's been this way for at least the last month.  I've tried different computers, browsers, etc. and all return the same result.  Anyone know the cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

[Paypal Sandbox cannot delete testing account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5E3P.jpg)

I think this is the issue you are referring to, and I have not been able to solve it either even after multiple emails to PayPal. I tried to delete the top email from the screenshot (one I manually created) and I get the error message shown at the top of the screenshot.

Comment: This is better as a comment

Comment: I get this too (Sweden), any solution? I can create a personal sandbox account but not business. I get status=error and cannot delete them!

Comment: I am also suffering from the same problem. I cannot delete a sandbox account, the 'Delete account' link is not present.

Answer (score 0):

### For Creating Accounts

**try deleting all local browser data. It should let you create accounts after doing this**

[image]

### For Deleting Accounts

Do same as create account and also **make sure you don't have any active paypal subscription To or From that account**.